# Uncheck checkbox if checked with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes in a row and this code I found works GREAT

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

However,  I have a business requirement in which I'm told if someone clicks on a checkbox that is already checked, that it must uncheck.  Yes I understand that radio buttons typically are used in the "only allow 1 item to be selected"  however even a radio button is not something you can click to "de-select"

Checkboxes are more natural to be able to un-select but with my function I was trying unselect if already selected and clicked and it always goes to the else statement

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
    //alert('c');
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);

  if ($(this).checked)
  {
      alert('f');
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
  else {
      alert('t');
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }

});
```

**Summary**

There are 3 checkboxes , currently my function only allows 1 of them to be checked. However now I need to be able to click on the currently checked checkbox and uncheck it

[image]

Comment: What do you want? Explain in parts and better way.

Comment: There are 3 checkboxes ,  currently my function only allows 1 of them to be checked.   However now I need to be able to click on the currently checked checkbox and uncheck it

Comment: with `$(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);` you uncheck the clicked checkbox, that's why it always goes to `else` statement

Comment: So why is it that you can't just use radio buttons? If you only want 1 checkbox to be selected per row that's exactly what a radio button would do.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, so I do want to use that code but wrap a conditional around it checking it the checkbox is checked already and being clicked on because I do need to allow for unselecting of all of them

Comment: @Rafa    Radio buttons make zero sense because it is a series of business questions that are optional, and they do not want someone to be "stuck" with "accidentally clicking on one.   This is not the simple SAT or high school /college type thing of   "check   Yes, No or Both Or None "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just omit the clicked checkbox when setting `checked = false` on checkboxes in that row, so that it will behave like a regular checkbox, eg:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69954ush/)